# My video crashing when I try to render it

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Why render crashing, how to fix it? Below I will describe the details of my video.
I also tried to render through the console, it did not work, I will attach the error below.

My notebook settings:
Model - hp 15-r157nr
CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz 2.40 GHz
GPU - Geforce 820M
RAM - 8 Gb

My video uses a speed modifier and compresses the original video which is almost 4 hours long. As a result, the video now runs for 14 minutes. I use proxy video when working in VSE
[image: VSE Strips]

I render at 24 fps when rendering.
[image]
[image: 24 fpc]

In the encoding settings, I select the MP4 preset.
[image]
[image: encoding settings]

Settings of VCE in Preferences.
[image]

It is also worth mentioning that it seems my graphics card is not suitable for working with Blender.
[image]

My attempt to render through the console and the error that followed. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9IW96FisnU) tutorial on which I tried to render through the console.

( I found the answer - Console rendering gave an error because the path to the blender file was incorrect - some directories had spaces in their names. The names must be without spaces, then everything will work )
[image]

Comment: I've also noticed that the Speed modifier makes Blender crash, maybe it's a bug?

Comment: If I were you, I would try to disable some addons (for example Order 66 and VSEQF which seems to give an error) and see if the crashes still occur.

Comment: @moonboots It seems that the Speed modifier can really break the render.

Comment: @Husch I disabled these addons, the errors were gone, but the problem persisted. I was able to render the video only when I rendered the sequence of video images under the Speed modifier, loaded this sequence and rendered the video with it already, without any Speed modifier. And it worked.

Comment: I guess it worth a bug report

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a matter of the Speed modifier. Maybe under certain circumstances it can somehow influence the successful outcome of the render.

In my case, I somehow accelerated my video into an image sequence. Rendered through the console, there were about 3-4 crashes, but I finished the render.

After that I loaded the resulting sequence into Blender and rendered the final video with it, without the Speed modifier. Everything was rendered perfectly, no crashes.